# Angular drag and drop for array of object

Tags: angular, typescript

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';


@Component({
  selector: 'kt-manage-menu',
  templateUrl: './manage-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manage-menu.component.scss']
})
export class ManageMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  movies = [
    {
      id:1, title:'Beauty and the best'
    },
    {
      id:2, title:'Spider Man'
    }
   ]

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.movies, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
}
```

Example is here : https://stackblitz.com/angular/omybvaablxk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-custom-placeholder-example.ts

**How I can create Angular drag and drop for array of object please ?
I try it by array of string only it works but by  array of objects don't .. I try interface method but it isn't work also

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cdk-drag-drop-custom-placeholder-example.html, just change the following

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let movie of movies" cdkDrag>
    <div class="example-custom-placeholder" *cdkDragPlaceholder></div>

    {{movie.title}}       -------------->  Do this instead of movie, this will iterate over the object titles.

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes I clicked on check mark it display warning for me : You can accept an answer in 3 minutes

Comment: yeah , you can do it after 3 mins.